# Bumblebee and Nvidia Settings: external monitor

Tags: nvidia, display, bumblebee, external-monitor

I just installed bumblebee. I'm finally able to enter into Nvidia X Settings using the "optirun"command. This is all great, but now I would like to get my second monitor working via the HDMI port. I've read some suggestions from folks using their Lenovo Thinkpads etc...there seems to be 3 options, switch to discrete graphics in the BIOS and force the proprietary drivers to run, and then make some editions to xorg.conf file, or switch to integrated graphics in the BIOS, or run Optimus using Bumblebee and then make some editions to the bumblebee xorg.conf file. I'm running a Lenovo U460s with a Nvidia GT 218 (GeForce 305M) card in it. I want to be able to use my Vizio LCD TV as a monitor while at home and then the laptop's screen while out and about. Any thoughts about the best/easiest approach to make this happen? Also, what's "Disper" and how do I install and use it?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!